# What exactly do you do and say when you fall Korim?

Tags: tefilla, yom-kippur, bowing-kneeling

Some people have a custom of bowing during Musaf on Yom Kippur ("*Korim*"). What exactly do you do and say when you fall Korim on Yom Kipur?

Comment: I don't know if I've heard this term before. Here it is in a book:
http://books.google.com/books?id=cffhcpSfOrAC&pg=PA385&lpg=PA385&dq=%22fall+korim%22&source=bl&ots=-9rdDb82ql&sig=9Kzo-eFGAJan5Hte2ATQ-ctIsNk&hl=en&ei=2ySRTMT4K8H_lgfphaXkAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAw

Comment: Would appreciate if someone discussed what women do. They have a very specific procedure (that does not involve prostrating oneself on the floor) but I don't really know it. @MonicaCellio ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know (there may be variant customs):

In Aleinu: kneel at כורעים, prostrate (head and hands to the ground, while still kneeling - essentially, a fetal position) at ומשתחוים, stay that way until הקדוש ברוך הוא, and then get up.

In the Avodah: kneel at כורעים, prostrate at ומשתחוים, and stay that way until לעולם ועד.

[In all cases, if it's a stone floor, halachah mandates that you put something on it beforehand (such as a towel), because one may not prostrate oneself on a stone floor outside of the Beis Hamikdash. Some have the custom to do so regardless of what the floor is made of.]

Comment: When covering the floor which part of your body goes on the covering?

Comment: I recall hearing in ... shul or yeshiva? ... that it's the HEAD that's important to have covering, not the knees.  Anyone back me up here?

Comment: You might be right - I see where Mishnah Berurah (131:40) discusses specifically head-bowing (kidah) or prostration (hishtachavayah) as being problematic, but not kneeling (kidah).

Comment: Shalom, I have the same recollection. Also, I don't think fetal is the target position when prostrating oneself. According at least to one YU ראש ישיבה, it means lying fully face-down on the floor with arms outstretched in front.

Comment: Prostration (outstretched) on a stone floor is an issur d'oraisa (even maskis). The chachamim were gozer on a non-stone floor atu stone floor. Kida (fetal) on stone is an issur d'rabbanan as well atu prostration. If you have "tarti l'malyusa" it is mutar: kida not on stone, or leaning to the side with either kida (even on stone) or prostration (not on stone). Summary of MB 131:40